# How Apply Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table Tab1  and Tab2.  Tab1 contain some data but Tab2 doesn't contain any data in present but in future it may be contain data . Now i want to apply join b/w both table

Tab1

```
Id Name
1    A
2    B
```

Tab2

```
Id   Class
```

if Tab2 is Null table then data of Tab1 table must be show and Column of Tab2 Table must be contain..

Like

```
ID  Name  Class
1   A     NULL
2   B     NULL
3   C     NULL
```

So please help me how can I obtain such output?

Comment: post the code you have so far, you can also search on this site for other questions about doing joins

Comment: Where did (3,C) come from?

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`Left Join`**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

```
select 
    a.Id, a.Name, b.Class 
from 
    Table_A a 
left join 
    Table_B b on a.Id = b.Id
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    Tab1.id, Tab1.name, Tab2.class 
FROM
    Tab1 
LEFT JOIN
    Tab2 ON Tab1.id = Tab2.id
```

Comment: Same answer was already given 1 hour previously to this.

Comment: Sorry !! Seems to be newbie Mistake, I copy pasted to add more details on this, but it got automatically posted.